# How to call the idiom of using an array to apply a function to a variadic pack

Tags: c++, c++11, variadic-templates, idioms

Here is the idiom in question:

```
template<typename... T>
void f(T... t) {
    int temp[] = {(g(t), 0)...};
}
```

This will be compiled as `g(t0); g(t1); ...`, order of function calls is guaranteed by C++11[dcl.init.list]/4.
A better version uses `std::initializer_list` instead of array, but it's not important here.

The question is: **how should we call this idiom?**

**Upd:**
Basically, it's the idiom which we should advise to people to use it instead of recursion, i.e. to replace two overloads
`void f() {}`
`void f(H head, T... tail) { g(head); f(tail...); }`
with single
`void f(T... t) { int temp[]{(g(t), 0)...}; }`

Of course we can call it "An idiom which will be replaced by the [Fold Expressions](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n4295.html)" but I hope there is a proper term for it.

Comment: Btw, in C++1z this probably will be replaced by [Fold Expressions](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n4295.html)

Comment: "pack expansion" seems to cover it, yes?

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf, thanks, fixed. No, it's not just a  "pack expansion" - using of the array plays a key part here. It's kinda "this idion vs recursion" thing

Comment: yes, checked, the C++11 standard calls exactly this code a pack expansion, in §5.1.2/23.

Comment: "pack expansion" is just `t...`

Comment: the formal *pattern* in your case is `g(t)`.

Comment: I may be blind, but I can't find the place in C++11 §14.5.3/4 where it allows pack expansion in function calls (as clearly is valid)?

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf well the "pattern" (as in 14.5.3/4) is `(g(t), 0)` where `,` is `operator,`

Comment: yes. but can you help with finding formal stuff about parameter pack expansion as function call arguments?

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf oh, it's funny but I also can't find it. However the example that the end of 14.5.3/4 clearly shows a pack expansion in a function call

Comment: I believe the cool kids on SO refer to this as "the indices trick," although it has no formal name. I personally use `std::initializer_list<int>` instead of `int[]` so that I don't need the extra `0,` to defend against empty parameter packs.

Answer (score 1):

Pack expansion.

C++11 §5.1.2/23 in [expr.prim.lambda]:

> **”** A *capture* followed by an ellipsis is a pack expansion (14.5.3). [*Example:*
>
> ```
> template<class... Args>
> void f(Args... args) {
>   auto lm = [&, args...] { return g(args...); };
>   lm();
> }
> ```
>
> *—end example* ]

I think that covers it. The pack expansion without applying a function can be viewed as one applying an identity function.

C++11 §14.5.3/4 in [temp.variadic]:

> A *pack expansion* consists of a *pattern* and an ellipsis, the instantiation of which produces zero or more
>   instantiations of the pattern in a list (described below). […]

Comment: nope, it's not about Pack expansion. It's like the (in)famous `0 == x` idiom is not about `operator==`. It's about how you replace recursive unpacking with pack expansion inside a braced-initializer.

Comment: How about, "*using* pack expansion" then?

Comment: no-no, look - with recursive approach we also have pack expansion - `void f(H h, T... t) { g(h); f(t...); }`

Comment: and this is `int tmp[]{(g(t), 0)...};` vs `g(h); f(t...);`

Comment: "complete pack expansion"?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps "function call expanded across parameter pack"?

Comment: well I believe that it should have "array" in its name, because e.g. using a helper function `template<class... T> void eat(T...) {}` and then `eat(g(t)...);` also is a  "function call expanded across parameter pack" but it doesn't do the thing - order of calls is not guaranteed.

Answer (score 0):

Let's distinguish folding and mapping.
fold turns series of input data to a single value.
map turns series of inputs to series of outputs.
(Of course, mapping may be expressed as folding series of scalars to a single list).

Here we map all inputs to a nullary value.
If we highlight side effects of g(x0), g(x1), etc - we can talk about mapping.
If we highlight producing void, - we can talk about pure folding. But this is meaningless, I think.

std::transform is mapping. std::accumulate is folding. What is std::for_each? Mapping or folding? (BTW, it is folding, because it returns a stateful function object with accumulated state).
As far as the input function is unary, not binary, it is mapping (fused with folding).

So. I'd like to give this idiom "variadic for-each".